# Using KnockoutJS 2.2.0 & jQuery 1.8.2 remove all bindings from all children of #someDiv

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I'm wanting to delete All bindings (ko.cleanNode) from all child elements of a certain div. 
Must be a noobie question but I can't figure out how to use jQuery to loop through all childre, grand-children, great-grand-children, etc. whilst having KnockoutJS remove the bindings of all the DOM elements.

I do NOT want to remove the elements from the DOM. This is a single page application, therefore the elements are pre-loaded as embedded resources and don't get resend to a client if they were to visit the page again. If a client revisits that part of the application I'll have a function rebind the necessary elements, which currently works fine.

Current setup:

```
<html>
<head>
//loading all resources
</head>
<body>
//load first element using some obscure setup
<div id="firsPage" data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header">@Global.header</div>
    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
         <label for="firstInput" />
         <input id="firstInput some other stuff />
    </div>
    <div data-role="datebox <!-- some settings --> >
         //creates table using jQuery mobile (lots of (great-)(grand-)children)
    </div>
    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <div id="secondInput">
            <div class="checklist">
                <ul>
                    <li />
                    <li />
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
//Here the whole thing starts again 
<div id="secondPage" data-role="page">
    <!-- repeat above innerHTML in your mind ;) -->
</div>
//And here again! and again...
</body>
```

The problem I'm having is that bindings of the children don't seem to get "cleaned up" when i use

```
ko.cleanNode($('#firstPage')[0]);
```

Or when I get the Element into a variable and then format it to ko.cleanNode($element).

Is there a way to do this? Been staring at it for a good few hours now, so probably overlooking a way too obvious way of doing it...

Thanks!

**EDIT:** below is the error I'm getting:
Uncaught Error: Unable to parse bindings.
Message: ReferenceError: someDate is not defined;
Bindings Value: value: someDate

This ko.observable 'someDate' however no longer exists as a binding on the "data-role='page'" that I'm navigating to. For some reason it continues to want to bind with this value. If I use removeNode() I have no such problems, I then have the problem that I'm missing a DOM element containing an entire page.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried?:

```
$('#firstPage').undatabind();
```

**UPDATE:**

Sorry, this method is part of the Knockout Programmatic plugin I use, as @NukeFace has pointed out.

Cheers.

Comment: I've tried the .unbind(), doesn't work. KnockoutJS continues to try and bind a value that should no longer exist as a binding after the cleanNode().

Comment: You mean .undatabind() (you wrote "unbind")?

Comment: .undatabind() threw an error, function didn't exist, so went on a little hunt ;) But didn't solve the issue as the bindings are KnockoutJS bindings. Most likely already have a solution though. Loading entire divs (with children structure of say #firstPage) into a jQuery variable, and just deleting the entire thing from the DOM once done. If a client returns to #firstPage, it's simply reloadable  with $.load("#content", firstPageVar) (or something looking like it).

Comment: that is not possible. undatabind() definitely exists. Take a look at this example i have in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vtortola/wx8cL/ it is using undatabind to remove the template of one of the items of the collection and replace it with other.

Comment: Hmmm sure is strange. Maybe the framework I'm using from the company I'm at has then somehow overridden it, seeing as how .unbind() didn't do the trick either. Will have to wait and see what comes out of a meeting monday morning when a framework dev, an architect and another dev are back at the office. Having a meeting to figure out whether to dump the framework all together or radically alter it. Thanks for your help though! If I find out what was causing it I'll let you know!

Comment: Btw, yes, I was just now guessing the framework has overridden it. Though I have read access I can't change it myself. Has been annoying me for a wee while now ;)

Comment: Good, keep this updated. You never know when am I going to be in a similar mess haha

Comment: Right... To keep you updated ;) Haven't got it all the way proper yet but seems to function with the least amount of binding residue left behind so far. After loading the KnockoutJS.js library, I've set it to perform a few additional functions. 

//Remove bindings when hiding page
`$('[data-ko-bind*="page"]').live('pagehide', function (event, ui) { ko.cleanNode(ui); });`
//Bind model to view on pageinit event
`$('[data-ko-bind="pageinit"]').live('pageinit', function (event, ui) { bindViewModel(this, 'pageinit'); });`

bindViewModel searches for Model + View combi to apply bindings. 
However...

Comment: This doesn't work all the way properly. It removes pretty much everything but still keeps some of it somewhere. When logging in the console I get: Came from: undefined, Went to: Page1. Came from Page1, Went to: Page0, Went to Page0. Came from: Page0, Went to: Page1, Went to Page1, Went to: Page1.    And so on. Therefore still something remains, though double execution of code seems to be resolved.

Comment: Btw, I've found .undatabind(). It's part of Knockout Programmatic which you used in your jsfiddle example. However it's not part of default jQuery or KnockoutJS. Just as a side note ;)

Comment: Last day tomorrow on this project for me. Back to school ;) I've send Knockout Programmatic as a possible solution to the developers whom will continue the development. Hopefully that will provide a more complete solution as the one I've been able to create thus far. So alas, there won't be any more updates from me on this matter.